# Show/Hide element on hover with sliding jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

I'm having a bit of difficulty and can't seem to find an answer.

So, I've got a class of images called `.accom-img` and a class of divs with descriptions called `.accom-desc`. When I hover over the `.accom-img` I hide that with a `slideUp()` and I show the `.accom-desc` (which are hidden on pageload but situated directly under them) with just `.show()`.

When the mouse leaves the `.accom-desc` I want the image to slide back down. I can get everything to work except when the mouse leaves the `.accom-desc`. The image just stays hidden.

Please help me with what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

```js
       jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.accom-desc').hide();

     jQuery('.accom-img').hover(function() {
      jQuery('.accom-img').slideUp();
     }, function() {
           jQuery('.accom-desc').show();
     });

     jQuery('.accom-desc').mouseleave(function() {
      jQuery('.accom-img').slideDown();
     }, function() {
            jQuery('.accom-desc').hide();
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accom-container">
  <div class="accom-desc"> 
    <h4>6 Sleeper House</h6> 
    <ul class="accom-ul"> 
      <li>2 x en-suite bedrooms each with a double bed with mosquito net.</li> 
      <li>2 x single beds with mosquito nets in the living area.</li> 
      <li>Fridge and chest freezer and fully fitted kitchen.</li> 
      <li>Television with DVD-player..bring lots of DVD's and own DSTV- decoder.(DSTV dish and connection available)</li> <li>Own private Jacuzzi</li> 
    </ul> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi iwanzbiz , welcome to stackoverflow, Could you please post your HTML code ?

Comment: Hi, thanks, the answer from S. Nadezhnyy worked for me, I'll be sure to post the HTML as well in future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because your functions run simultaneously. You need to do something like this:

```
jQuery('.accom-desc').mouseleave(function() {
        jQuery('.accom-img').slideDown(1000, function() {
        jQuery('.accom-desc').hide();
    }));
```